# Inserting multiple dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, sql-insert

Hi I would like to ask if it's possible to input dates starting from 01-01-2020 to 04-15-2020.
Currently I have this code to iterate or to keep looping for each day from 00:00:00 to 23:00:00.

```
    INSERT INTO dashboard.availability(terminal_id, availability_date, availability_time)
    select td.terminal_id, td.down_date, (hh * interval '1 hour')::time
     from (select distinct terminal_id, down_date
      from dashboard.down_event
     ) td cross join
     generate_series(0, 23) gs(hh);
```

But can i also do it the same for the date looping each day until the date reached 2020-04-15?

For example:

```
terminal_id            availability_time     availability_date
   _____________     ___________________   _____________________
    012345678             00:00:00             2020-01-01
    012345678             01:00:00             2020-01-01
    012345678             02:00:00             2020-01-01
    012345678             03:00:00             2020-01-01
.
.
.  
   012345678             00:00:00               2020-04-15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into dashboard.availability(terminal_id, availability_date, availability_time)
select t.terminal_id, x.ts::date, x.ts::time
from (select distinct terminal_id from dashboard.down_event) t
cross join generate_series(date '2020-01-01', date '2020-04-15', interval '1 hour') x(ts)
```

For each `terminal_id` in table `dashboard.down_event`, this generates one row per hour between the January 1st and April 15th. The results are inserted into the target table, while keeping the date and time components in separate columns.

Side note: storing the data and time componnents of a timestamp in different columns is usually not a good idea; it makes things more complicated and less efficient when you actually need to access the timestamp value (which does happen, sooner or later).

Comment: Thanks! Noted on your side note!

Comment: Hi! I've looked the date for '2020-04-15' it only goes for 00:00:00 not 23:00:00

Comment: @ElijahLeis: right, so: `generate_series(date '2020-01-01', date '2020-04-16', interval '1 hour')`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just iterate by hour over the entire timeperiod?

```
select td.terminal_id, gs.down_date
from (select distinct terminal_id
      from dashboard.down_event
     ) td cross join
     generate_series('2020-01-01'::timestamp, '2020-04-15'::timestamp, interval '1 hour) gs(down_date);
```

Comment: How about the time? The query above only gets 2 columns. But I need to insert 3 SELECTS

Comment: @ElijahLeis . . . The second column has both the date and the time.  That seems like a feature, not a bug, but you can obvious extract the date and time values from it.